# PHP ftp_get(): Prohibited file name

Tags: php, ftp

I have a PHP script where I connect to a FTP and try to download some files to my server.

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$ftp_username='x';
$ftp_userpass='xx';
// connect and login to FTP server
$ftp_server = "xxx";

$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server)or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);

// Obtener los archivos contenidos en el directorio actual
$contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, ".");

foreach ($contents as $file) {
        $local_file = $file;
        $server_file =$file;

        // try download $server_file and save it in $local_file
        if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
            echo "Everything OK\n";
        } else {
            echo "There is a problem\n";
        }
    }
}
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

This error prompts, and file cant be download:

> Warning: ftp_get(): Prohibited file name: .\Vivotek - GFSF123E-20180321-0850043966.jpg in C:\xDEVSERVER\eds-www\conftp.php on line ...
>   There is a problem

I tried to change the file's name to somtehing basic and simple (p.e. 0850043966.jpg), but error persists.Any help? Suggestion?

Comment: Can you even create a file in the script path on the webserver? What does this do? `file_put_contents('0850043966.jpg', 'foo');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using the filenames received by `ftp_nlist` to name the file stored locally.

In your case the filenames received by `ftp_nlist` have a leading `.\` that renders them unsuitable for local storage.

You may just cut away the prefix:

```
$local_file = substr( $file, 2 );
```